# sizeWithFont Returns a width 0

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, core-graphics, sizewithfont

My ultimate goal is to vary the font size so that various words fit in the same rectangular area.  I thought sizeWithFont would be a great method to use but I keep getting a width of 0 and I'm confused.

```
NSString *name = @"Test Word";
CGFloat fontSize = 32.0;
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"TimeNewRomanPSMT" size: fontSize]; 
CGSize sWidth = [name sizeWithFont:font 
             constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(fontSize, CGFLOAT_MAX)
          lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
NSLog(@"sWidth =  %3.1f; rec.width n= %3.1f ", sWidth.width, rec.width);
```

My plan is to loop through font sizes until the width fits but sWidth.width keeps returning 0.

Chris

Answer (score 6):

The font name is TimesNewRomanPSMT  and no TimeNewRomanPSMT.

Notice the s after Times, a common error!

This web site is very helpful to validate the font names as well as listing and having an example of all fonts available in iOS:

http://iosfonts.com/

Comment: Dude, you are awesome.  Changed it to AmericanTypewriter and it worked fine.  Still, why didn't the compiler catch this?

Comment: The font name is a string and checked at runtime, it is  a string that is checked against the fonts on the particular OS you are running. I agree that this is error prone, I personally prefer putting it in a constant.

Comment: From anonymous user: The compiler does not catch this because it's not a compilation error. It is not aware what fonts are available.. and doesn't check. As soon as a font with that name would be available, it would work.

Answer (score 1):

the first thing that you should suggest and check in this case - that your font is not `nil`. It can happen if you entered not correct font name